# Rails YAML unable to retrieve carriage return from mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

Say I have a model `SomeResource` which has attribute `data`

```
a = SomeResource.find 1
a.data = "abc"
a.save
```

In mysql

```
select length(data) from some_resources where id = 1;
+--------------+
| length(data) |
+--------------+
|            8 |
+--------------+
```

Now,

```
a.data = "abc\r"
#=> #<SomeResource id: XX,.., data: "abc\r",..>
a.save
```

Checking if it's stored in mysql

```
select length(data) from some_resources where id = 1;
+--------------+
| length(data) |
+--------------+
|            9 |
+--------------+
```

Clearly the length increases, indicating the new character is stored in the database.

Trying to retrieve it back in rails console:

```
a = SomeResource.find 1
a.data
#=> "abc"
```

`\r` is getting lost.

Why is carriage return lost?

MySql Details:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.5.38                  |
| protocol_version        | 10                      |
| slave_type_conversions  |                         |
| version                 | 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                  |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu        |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Rails Version:
`Rails 3.2.13`

Ruby Version: `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-06-29 patchlevel 370) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: `a.data = "abc\r"`; the show `a.data` in the console, and provide it here

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please provide MySQL version and the collate of your database. Also provide Rails version.

Comment: updated my question to provide information demanded here in comments.